# Computer shuts down from time to time

Tags: debian, crash

While I'm working on the computer, the monitor sometimes suddenly goes black and it starts outputting lines like below in ~7 seconds intervals.

```
[  127.759539] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000001 Count 00002a11
[  135.955830] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000001 Count 00002a12
[  144.148118] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000001 Count 00002a13
```

[image]

It goes on forever and I can't really get back to the system unless I reboot the computer.

Once I reboot it everything works fine for a couple of days, but eventually it shows up again.

**Does anybody have an idea to what it is and how I can solve this?**

Using Debian 9

Comment: Is your NVIDIA graphics card overheating? What are you doing when this happens?

Comment: @Kusalananda It usually happens within 20-30 minutes of turning my computer on, so I don't suspect overheating. I also run Windows from this computer (for playing games) and I've never had any issues from Windows

Comment: Accorting to [XID Errors Table](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html), `Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16` means `Display engine hung`. IMHO, this seems a driver problem. Which driver are you using? NVIDIA proprietary or open source one? Latest version? What does it happen if you change driver source?

Comment: Binary NVIDIA driver is quick, but it is a crap. If you don't need 3D gaming, use nouveau (opensource nvidia drivers).